# Unable to get complete data using pyserial when compared to logs from putty

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I am looking for options to collect serial log using python. Tried the pyserial module but I get incomplete logs when compare to logs collected using putty
Below is code that I am using.

```
def getSerialLogs(comport, fileName='SerialLog.txt', baudrate=115200):
    ser = serial.Serial(comport, baudrate, xonxoff =True, timeout=20)
    sio = io.TextIOWrapper(
        io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser, 100)
    )
    with open(fileName, 'a') as f:
        while ser.isOpen():
            datastring = sio.readline()
            f.write(datastring)
```

These logs are collected during android device boot.

Comment: What do you mean by incomplete? Can you post what you get in putty and what you get with your code so we can see the differences?

Comment: After some more debugging observed that complete logs are obtained after I kill the python script running this function. How can I cleanly exit from this function?

Comment: the loop that is keeping your function running is `while ser.isOpen():`, just close the connection so `ser.isOpen` is no longer True. Don't kill the script